# Panda Data frame plot by year. Need code to generate the image like attached

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linechart

I have a data in the csv file as given in the below format, I'm not sure how to arrange this data to get the image which is attached below

```
creation_time   physical_device_type
---------------   --------------------
7/25/2018 14:53   email
7/26/2018 14:53   printer
7/26/2017 14:53   email 
7/24/2017 14:53   printer
7/23/2017 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   fax
7/22/2019 14:53   fax
```

I want to get the below chart like below,

[image: ![sampel chart]

Count should be come in the y axis and year should come in the X axis

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/test/test.csv');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `parse_dates` parameter to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for datetime column, then use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) for count and last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/test/test.csv', parse_dates=['creation_time'])

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['creation_time'].dt.year, df['physical_device_type'])
print (df1)
physical_device_type  email  fax  printer
creation_time                            
2017                      2    0        1
2018                      1    0        1
2019                      1    2        0

df1.plot()
```

Comment: in  the x axis im getting the year in decimal nos like 2016.00 , 2016.25 like that , i need only 2016 , 2017 , 2018 like that?

Comment: @KarthikSV - what about change `df['creation_time'].dt.year` to `df['creation_time'].dt.year.astype(str)` ?